# Rounding output to 2 decimals

Tags: javascript

I've coded a small compound interest calculator. The last output-field has to show the amount calculated with the inputs above. But it should be rounded to two decimals and I didn't get it to work with various code-snippets I found on the web and even stackoverflow.

```
var $button9 = $('.increment-btn5'); // button to call the function below
var $counter1 = $('.counter1'); // First input
var $counter2 = $('.counter2'); // obsolete var at the moment
var $counter3 = $('.counter3'); // Second input
var $counter4 = $('.counter4'); // Third input
var $counter5 = $('.counter5'); // Ouput

$button9.click(function(){
  $counter5.val( parseInt($counter1.val()) * ((parseInt($counter4.val()) / 100) + 1) ** parseInt($counter3.val() )  ); // Calculates amount and loads it into .counter5
```

Useful ideas would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: it might work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `Number.toFixed` yet?

```js
var $button9 = $('.increment-btn5'); // button to call the function below
var $counter1 = $('.counter1'); // First input
var $counter2 = $('.counter2'); // obsolete var at the moment
var $counter3 = $('.counter3'); // Second input
var $counter4 = $('.counter4'); // Third input
var $counter5 = $('.counter5'); // Ouput

$button9.click(function(){
  $counter5.val( 
    ( // begin calculation
      parseInt($counter1.val()) * 
      ((parseInt($counter4.val()) / 100) + 1) ** 
      parseInt($counter3.val() ) 
    ) // end calculation
    .toFixed(2) // round it to two decimals
  ); // pass it to counter5
});
```

Comment: Indeed, that was the first thing I've tried. But it won't work.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Do you get an error message?